# Laravel ORM list groupBy related records

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, group-by, relationship

I have 2 tables:
images - contains id, room_id, floor_id etc. information, 
objects - contains images_id, object.

Relationships:
image hasMany objects
object hasOne image

I want to group images by room_id and then list all objects for room based on these grouped images.

Currently I have 2 queries:

```
Images::where('floor_id', '=', $floor_id)
       ->groupBy('room_id')->get(array('*', DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(id) as rooms')));
```

and then I loop through all image groups and look for objects in them.

```
Objects::whereIn('images_id', explode(',', $rooms))->get()
```

**Is it possible to merge these 2 queries into 1 and if so, then how?**

I tried with eager loading but still groupBy messed everything up.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. To save the extra query you can utilise the returned collection and group by that instead.

```
Images::where('floor_id', '=', $floor_id)
    ->with('objects')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('room_id');
```